# How to resolve parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am trying to deploy my react native function to Firebase. The pre-conigured firebase function (helloWorld)seems to deploy correctly so I am definitely connected to Firebase. I am trying to deploy my own function which is the chatGPT API and followed the syntax of the initial pre-configured function. The function is a node environment which receives data and sends the data to the chatGPT API which is the completetion function below in the code. It seems that 'await' is already a reserved keyword so I have tried putting 'async' in multiple places but can't seem to deploy this to firebase

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions"); // Firebase initial function
const OpenAIApi = require("openai") // ChatGPT dependency 
const Configuration = require("openai")// ChatGPT dependency 
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// // Create and deploy your first functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.firebasePromptReceiver = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
if (!configuration.apiKey) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: {
        message:
          'OpenAI API key not configured, please follow instructions in README.md',
      },
    });
    return;
  }

  const prompt = request.body.prompt || '';

  if (prompt.trim().length === 0) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: {
        message: 'Please enter a valid prompt',
      },
    });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const completion = await openai.createCompletion({  //ChatGPT API
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt: generatePrompt(prompt),
      temperature: 0.9,
      max_tokens: 2048,
    });
    response.status(200).json({result: completion.data.choices[0].text});
    console.log(completion);
  } catch (error) {
    // Consider adjusting the error handling logic for your use case
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.status, error.response.data);
      res.status(error.response.status).json(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.error(`Error with OpenAI API request: ${error.message}`);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: {
          message: 'An error occurred during your request.',
        },
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Please any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try async function? `.onRequest(async (request, response) ...`

Comment: Currently there isn't an official ChatGPT API. Please clarify what you mean by ChatGPT API.

Answer (score 1):

```
functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {..}
```

`await` operator sould be used in async function